# ImageIO Unsupported Image Type - TwelveMonkeys Plugin with fix not working?

Tags: java, compression, javax.imageio, twelvemonkeys

I encountered the Unsupported Image Type error due to an incompatible colour profile using `com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader`. I later found the TwelveMonkeys plugins that are proven to fix this issue and have referenced the dependent .jars in my project classpath. I downloaded them from the TwelveMonkeys github repository. Note i'm using version 3.0.2 because I'm running on Java 6 with JDK 1.6.0_45. These are the .jars I've added to my project:

```
common-lang-3.0.2.jar
common-io-3.0.2.jar
common-image-3.0.2.jar
imageio-core-3.0.2.jar
imageio-metadata-3.0.2.jar
imageio-jpeg-3.0.2.jar
```

I was able to test the library is installed and working using the following test:

```
Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("JPEG");
while (readers.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("reader: " + readers.next());
}
```

Which outputs:

```
reader: com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader@4102799c
reader: com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader@33d6f122
```

When i run my code, it is still trying to read the JPEG with `com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader` and continues to throw the IIOException. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Its looking like iTextPDF is causing the issue which is a library used by the project. I setup a barebone test application that converts a CMYK JPEG to a `BufferedImage` and then calls `ImageIO.read(img)` and it works fine. I'm struggling to see a reason why iText wouldn't be finding the TwelveMonkeys plugin when it calls `ImageIO.read(img)` when they're in the same project and classpath, but that's probably due to my limited knowledge. I should also add that the application i'm working on is part of a web service API.

Comment: What does your code look like? What kind of application is this (ie. command line tool, Swing app, web app, other)? Did you run the test code in the same environment/application as the real code? Where is the full stack trace?

Comment: PS: Much better to ask a question like this! :-) I will not answer your comment on the other question, you might just as well delete it, as it is only noise.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for responding promptly :) 
I'm unable to post code unfortunately. It is worth mentioning though that I'm running the test code in the same environment, same project, as the code that's falling over; in the unit test class associated with the failing class. I have checked the class calling the failing code does recognize the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO reader as well and it's finding it fine, just not in execution.

Comment: Added an update to the question just now. Have further isolated the problem.

Comment: If you are deploying the plugins as part of a web application, make sure you read (and follow the instructions in) [this document](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app). Also, if you believe the problem is related to iText, you might want to add versions for that library as well. Maybe look at the source code for iText, to see if they do anything special...

Comment: @haraldK Thank you! Looks like it's working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As often is the case, when an ImageIO plugin isn't used at run-time from a web application, the cause is that the service provider isn't found because `ImageIO` is already initialized, and has invoked `scanForPlugins()` before the web app's libraries were available to the JVM.

From [Deploying [ImageIO] plugins in a web app](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app):

> Because the ImageIO plugin registry (the `IIORegistry`) is "VM global", it doesn't by default work well with servlet contexts. This is especially evident if you load plugins from the `WEB-INF/lib` or `classes` folder. Unless you add `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` somewhere in your code, the plugins might never be available at all.
>
> In addition, servlet contexts dynamically loads and unloads classes (using a new class loader per context). If you restart your application, old classes will by default remain in memory forever (because the next time `scanForPlugins` is called, it's another `ClassLoader` that scans/loads classes, and thus they will be new instances in the registry). If a read is attempted using one of the remaining "old" readers, weird exceptions (like `NullPointerExceptions` when accessing static final initialized fields or `NoClassDefFoundErrors` for uninitialized inner classes) may occur.
>
> To work around both the discovery problem and the resource leak, it is strongly recommended to use the `IIOProviderContextListener` that implements dynamic loading and unloading of ImageIO plugins for web applications.

The `IIOProviderContextListener` is contained in the `twelvemonkeys-servlet.jar`, and must be registered in your application's `web.xml` (or similar if using Spring or other framework). See the above link for details.

Another safe alternative to using the context listener, is to place the JAR files in the application server's shared or common lib folder, instead of the `WEB-INF/lib` folder inside your web application.

PS: The above problem/solution applies to ImageIO plugins in general, not just the TwelveMonkeys plugins. Because of this, the context listener has no dependencies to the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO plugins, and may be used with JAI ImageIO or other ImageIO plugins as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot applications where there is no web.xml, you need to register the `IIOProviderContextListener` in your `@SpringBootApplication` class which should extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        // Register the listener from Twelvemonkeys to support CMYK image handling with ImageIO
        servletContext.addListener(IIOProviderContextListener.class);
    }
```

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/16#issuecomment-326128071) where this is explained in more detail.