# TwelveMonkeys: ProgressListenerBase class not found when reading JPEG

Tags: java, image, twelvemonkeys

#### Error description

When uploading a picture, our project needs to do some post-upload processing. However, running the code after upload a JPEG file

```
BufferedImage bImg = ImageIO.read(file);
```

triggers the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/util/ProgressListenerBase
    at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(JPEGImageReaderSpi.java:126)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(ImageReaderSpi.java:320)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:529)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:513)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1443)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
```

Everything works well when uploading a PNG file.

#### Project configuration

Our Java EE 7 project initially requires TwelvesMonkeys to handle CMYK-encoded JPG images. The EAR is composed of:

- project-common (JAR)
- project-ejb (EJB)    => depends on project-common
- project-web (WAR)    => depends on project-common and project-ejb
- project-rest (WAR)   => depends on project-common and project-ejb

`project-common` has the TwelveMonkeys dependencies:

```
<!-- Image IO -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageio-jpeg</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageio-bmp</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

which are forwarded to the other components by transitivity. We only handled `.jp(e)g` and `.png`. We also use [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator) along with TwelveMonkeys.

#### Troubleshooting

1. Following the [documentation](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270343/imageio-unsupported-image-type-twelvemonkeys-plugin-with-fix-not-working), I have added the listener in `project-web`:

   ```
   <listener>
       <display-name>ImageIO service provider loader/unloader</display-name>
       <listener-class>com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.image.IIOProviderContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```

   Under Netbeans, the `com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/util/ProgressListenerBase` is present in `project-ejb` and `project-web` so I don't understand why the class is not found
2. Regardless if the `ImageIO.read(file)` is called in `project-ejb` or `project-web`, the error is the same
3. I tried adding `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` before `ImageIO.read(file)`, the error is the same

#### Workaround

Following

> Another safe option, is to place the JAR files in the application server's shared or common lib folder.

I have manually put the dependencies

```
# common dependencies:
> common-image-3.3.2.jar
> common-io-3.3.2.jar
> common-lang-3.3.2.jar
# shared dependencies:
> imageio-core-3.3.2.jar
> imageio-metadata-3.3.2.jar
# TwelveMonkeys dependencies:
> imageio-jpeg-3.3.2.jar
> imageio-bmp-3.3.2.jar
# Servlet
> servlet-3.3.2.jar
```

in `{PAYARA_DIR}\glassfish\domains\{DOMAIN_NAME}\lib` folder **without** removing the listener. I changed the dependencies scope to`<scope>provided</scope>` as it is not embedded in the application.

I put it as a workaround because I understand that adding the listener should have been enough so that manually adding the dependencies seems overkill. Moreover, even if we don't change our dependencies version that often, changing TwelveMonkeys dependencies means that theses dependencies need to be manually updated and replaced.

**Question**: is this workaround only solution or where did I messed up?

Comment: I've never deployed ImageIO plugins as part of an EJB/EAR deployment, so I'm not really sure about this one. But one thing I would try, is to keep the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO dependencies local to the `project-web` only, and have the listener there. PS: Also note that you need to do a full server restart *after all artifacts have been updated* to avoid old instances of the plugins staying in the registry.

Comment: I'd like to avoid putting dependencies on war modules between we have multiple war modules and maybe TwelvesMonkeys will be required in one of them, that's why I'd like to keep it at application level. Noted for the full server restart and I confirm the point :)

Comment: I still suggest that you should try it, as a trouble shooting option, as it's known to work. It may also help us better understand the problem. My current understanding is that the problem is you have multiple instances of the plugins in your EAR, and the web-listener will only work for *that specific web app*. If you can place the plugin (and support) JARs in the EAR *only*, and create a similar thing as the web listener for the EAR, that *might* work.

Comment: @haraldK apologies late reply. Your assumption was correct:1) `imageio-jpeg`, `imageio-bmp`, `servlet` dependencies moved to `project-web`, It worked after server restart \o/. 2) Dependencies moved back to `common-project`: errors are back after server restart. 3) I re-did 1) and it worked back again after restart. Feel free to post an answer to get credits otherwise, I'll self-answer. However one question remains: My image manipulation methods are in `project-ejb`. How `project-ejb` uses TwelvesMonkey then ?

Comment: @haraldK for your information: I tried adding the listener and the dependencies in `project-rest` and it still works. I don't have image manipulation in my `project-rest` so this is as far as I can test. At this stage, dependencies are present in both war but not shared. I still don't understand how the EJB uses the dependencies then ^^.

Comment: Note that there are no compile-time dependencies from your EJB to the plugins, the EJB only use the ImageIO public API. Now, the reason it works (which is also why it caused problems) is that the ImageIO plugin registry is *shared* in the JVM. As long as the WAR with the plugins is loaded, any code in the JVM can use those plugins. This is a limitation in the ImageIO/Service provider implementation, unfortunately. It would have been cleaner if the plugins were only available to the application that loaded them. But that's not how it works.